# Plot multiple points

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

I have a matplotlib surface, I need to plot a collection of points on that surface. Below is the code that I have to create the surface:

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def graficar(fun):
    fig = plt.figure()
    ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')
    x = y = np.arange(-1.0, 1.0, 0.05)
    X, Y = np.meshgrid(x, y)
    zs = np.array(fun(np.ravel(X), np.ravel(Y)))
    Z = zs.reshape(X.shape) 
    ax.plot_surface(X, Y, Z)
    title='Graficación de la función'
    ax.set_title(title)
    ax.set_xlabel('X Label')
    ax.set_ylabel('Y Label')
    ax.set_zlabel('Z Label')
    plt.show()

#funcion x**2 + y**2
def funcion1(x, y):
    return (x)**2 + (y)**2

graficar(funcion1)
```

On the created surface I need to plot the points, for example, (-3, 3), (-2,2), (-1, 1), etc. This points need to be displayed on the surface itself, so 
I think that to do that I need to evaluate the point on the function, in my example (defined in function funcion1) if I evaluate the point (-2, 2), it will be (-2)**2 + (2)**2 = 4 +4 = 8, so the point will be x = -2, y = 2, z = 8, and I need that point displayed on the surface

How can I do this?

Comment: You also need to specify the third dimension’s coordinates to plot a point in 3d. Currently you have tuples of x, y coordinates. Or is it two points like x1 , x2 and y1,y2 and z1,z2? In that case, you can search for scatter3d function

Comment: @Sheldore yes, I think that to achieve that I need to evaluate the point on my function and I will get the Z, I edited the original question to clarify more.

Answer (score 0):

The following code should work for you:

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d.axes3d import get_test_data
# This import registers the 3D projection, but is otherwise unused.
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D  # noqa: F401 unused import

def randrange(n, vmin, vmax):
    '''
    Helper function to make an array of random numbers having shape (n, )
    with each number distributed Uniform(vmin, vmax).
    '''
    return (vmax - vmin)*np.random.rand(n) + vmin


def graficar(fun):
    fig = plt.figure()
    ax = fig.add_subplot(1, 1, 1, projection='3d')
    x = y = np.arange(-1.0, 1.0, 0.05)
    X, Y = np.meshgrid(x, y)
    zs = np.array(fun(np.ravel(X), np.ravel(Y)))
    Z = zs.reshape(X.shape)
    ax.plot_surface(X, Y, Z)
    title = 'Graficación de la función'
    ax.set_title(title)
    ax.set_xlabel('X Label')
    ax.set_ylabel('Y Label')
    ax.set_zlabel('Z Label')
    (xs, ys, zs) = ([0, 0.2, 1, 1.2, 0.3],
                    [-0.2, 0.3, 1.8, 0.7, 1.0], [1.0, 0.6, 0.4, 0.9, -0.5])
    ax.scatter(xs, ys, zs, c='r', marker='^')
    plt.show()

# funcion x**2 + y**2


def funcion1(x, y):
    return (x)**2 + (y)**2


graficar(funcion1)
```

This will give you the following plot:

[image: Plot from code]

Comment: Thanks, but what  I need is to plot the point on the surface itself, on the blue section of the graphic that you presented. I edited the original question to clarify more.